# How to achieve context menu in thymleaf?

Tags: jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to achieve context menu in thymeleaf dynamically.In this case "a href" is applied to whole list which is something like a data table click able. i need each list values to be clicked separately.

How to get the id of the menu which is clicked? so that i can pass the value of that id to get the sub menu of that id which is foreign key to that table.

**Thymeleaf Code**:

```
<ul id="menucatalog">
<div id="global-subnav">
<a href="catalog/partials/offers.html">
<li class="product_container" th:each="prod : ${menucataloglist}" th:text="${prod}">
</li></a>
</div>
</ul>
```

**Jquery Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menucatalog").menu();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add a  element inside your

element with the link you want. Something like

```
<li th:each="prod : ${menucataloglist}">
  <a href="whatever..." th:text="${prod}">My product</a>
</li>
```