# How to show context menus on table row click in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Can anyone please show me example code of how to show a Thymeleaf contextmenu when you click a table row and how to conditionally show values that will show in the thymeleaf contextmenu.

I am coming from a JSF/Primefaces background and they do it something like below:

```
<p:contextMenu id="contextMenu" for="tblUsers" widgetVar="contextMenu" event="x">
    <p:menuitem value="VIEW" action="#{userController.view()}" 
              rendered="#{userController.permitView}" />
    <p:menuitem value="EDIT" action="#{userController.edit()}"
              rendered="#{userController.permitEdit}" />
    <p:menuitem value="DELETE" action="#{userController.edit()}"
         rendered="#{userController.permitDelete}" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

Where userController is the controller and tblUser is the id of the datatable in question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve context menu in thymleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166584/how-to-achieve-context-menu-in-thymleaf)

Comment: There is not much in that answer on that link i saw it before i asked the question. Firstly they are talking about list items not table. Secondly it should ideally get the table row record that you click on and then manipulate the record based on what is in context menu items. In the documentation there as a th:contextmenu but i do not know how to use it. If i do not get an answer i guess i will have to try with javascript or javascript libraries. The link:  https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: The `th:contextmenu` attribute is converted to the [contextmenu attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contextmenu.asp). The `th:` prefix just makes the value could refer to an entry from java's `Model` (or whatever else expression language allows to do). You see, Thymeleaf is more like JSP/Freemarker, not like JSF/Primeface. It's a straightforward templating engine and does **not** provide with UI widgets. Therefore an example you've wrote is not really reproducible with plain Thymeleaf.